# How can I dynamically set up a mock for an enum property?

Tags: c#, generics, enums, moq

I'm trying to create a mock dynamically based on xml data. This works fine for most types, but enums turn out to be a bit tricky. The ??? in my code expects the type of the enum. But obviously the type is not known at compile time, so I'll have to resort to reflection. I'll probably have to use MakeGenericMethod to invoke Expression.Lambda directly or indirectly, but that seems to just move the problem as mock.Setup expects a compile time type as well. That's where I get stuck. Any help is appreciated.

```
public static Mock<T> DeserializeMock<T>(XElement node)
    where T : class
{
    var mock = new Mock<T>();

    foreach (var property in PropertyInfoHelper.EnumeratePublicAndInternalProperties(typeof(T)))
    {
        var attribute = node.Attribute(property.Name);

        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
            var body = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, property.Name);
            var propertyExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(body, parameter);
            mock.Setup(propertyExpression).Returns(attribute.Value);
        }

// ... other types omitted for brevity...

        else if (property.PropertyType.IsEnum)
        {
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
            var body = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, property.Name);
            var propertyExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, ???>>(body, parameter);
            mock.Setup(propertyExpression).Returns(convertToEnum(attribute.Value, property.PropertyType));
        }
    }

    return mock;
}
```

Comment: can't you do a property.GetType() and then create the enum using activator and then assign the value?

Comment: Creating the enum value is not the problem. I do that in the convertToEnum method. The problem is creating the propertyExpression. Using Activator you don't get compile time types. And moq methods require compile time types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would end up having to use reflection to get the types for the setup

```
//...omitted for brevity...

else if (property.PropertyType.IsEnum) {
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var body = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, property.Name);
    var delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T), property.PropertyType);
    var propertyExpression = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, body, parameter);
    var value = convertToEnum(attribute.Value, property.PropertyType);

    var setup = mock.GetType().GetMethods()
        .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Setup" && m.ContainsGenericParameters)
        .MakeGenericMethod(property.PropertyType);
    var result = setup.Invoke(mock, new object[] { propertyExpression });
    var returns = result.GetType().GetMethod("Returns", new[] { property.PropertyType });
    returns?.Invoke(result, new object[] { value });

}

//...omitted for brevity...
```

I also assume based on the original code that all the members being setup on the mock are either virtual or abstract members.

Proof of concept

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass {
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTestMethod() {
        //Arrange
        XElement element = new XElement("root",
            new XAttribute("MyProperty1", "Hello World"),
            new XAttribute("MyEnumProperty", "Value2")
        );

        //Act
        var mock = DeserializeMock<MyClass>(element);

        //Assert
        var actual = mock.Object;
        actual.MyEnumProperty.Should().Be(MyEnum.Value2);
        actual.MyProperty1.Should().Be("Hello World");
    }

    public class MyClass {
        public virtual string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
        public virtual MyEnum MyEnumProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public enum MyEnum {
        Value1,
        Value2
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for.